# Named Instance not working in Connection String in C# in a domain(network)-joined system

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

For two or three days I am facing a problem regarding sql express connection.
My LapTop has provided by a university, which is domain-joined computer.

My Problem is that I could not connect C# project in the laptop with SQL SERVER 2008R2 in the same laptop using named instance.
But I can connect when using the ip address

IP address changes regularly. because of that I have to change the connection string , which irritates.
Please Help me

Comment: As you mentioned you are facing some problem with sql express connection, I would suggest to post the error or sample code which you tried so that we can help you better.

Comment: There is no problem with named instances and domains. *Most* production databases run in domains. Post your connection string, code and error message

Comment: In any case, there can be only a single SQL Server Express instance, that's named SQLEXPRESS. Why don't you use `.\SQLEXPRESS` ?

Comment: Actually am working with unity C# code. Named pipes are enabled.Firewall set to off. Browser is running as Network instance. But when I give HP1\\SQLEXPRESS in the connection string as server, its not connecting. But when I tried with IP,port its working. I tried giving (local), ./SQLEXPRESS , (localDB) etc etc. But its not working.When I give tese to sql server management studio its all working. But from C# , its not connecting.   When I tried other user PC's or Laptops its working. Now You techies will get a clear picture. Is any laptop setting may cause the problem.

Comment: Is your laptop connected to the domain (is domain controller reachable)?

Comment: yes. The laptop under university domain. It's not personal. Full Computer Name is domain name + system Name

Answer (score 0):

If connecting to a SQL Server instance on your local machine, use the special keyword `(local)` as the Data Source. Note that the use of parentheses is required with using the keyword.

Reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/09/19/understanding-data-sourcelocal-in-sql-server-connection-strings/

Comment: The OP is asking about *named instances*

Comment: @Vauator (local) or (local)/SQLEXPRESS is required?

Comment: (local)\SQLEXPRESS. (local) is a keyword for your local machine, you still need the named instance of the SQL Server.

Comment: Ok. Thanks . I will try this. Will update the result here.

Comment: Actually. I tried with the  (local)/SQLEXPRESS , but did not work in that laptop. At last I put static localhost IP of the system , it's working fine now. Thank you all for the support.